# Share file between different local machine using scp cmd

Tags: encryption, openssl, git, github

I'm working on a cloud synced feature for my notes based on [this article](https://renerocks.ai/blog/obsidian-encrypted-github-android/)

[I try to share my git-crypt-key between my devices](https://renerocks.ai/blog/obsidian-encrypted-github-android/#checking-it-out-on-a-different-machine) (my PC and my laptop) in order to decrypt my remote GitHub repo where my notes are stored.

For this, I'm trying using the `scp` cmd as recommended in the article, but I'm not used to it so after doing some research on how to process SCP transfer, I've tried with this command :

```
scp username(origin)@hostname:filepath username(destination)@hostname:filepathdestination
```

then I get this error :

```
ssh: could not resolve hostname (hostname destination): Temporary failure in name resolution 
lost connection
```

So I tried changing the hostname with the IP address from my computer (probably the dumbest thing I've ever done since my IP address is the same on both devices) and then get this error :

```
ssh: connect to host .. port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

It may be relevant to say that :

1. I'm running WSL2 on my PC in order to use git-crypt
2. SSL and Openssl-server both installed on both devices
   (Openssl-server running on laptop)
3. I've already settled my SSH keys in order to push to GitHub

As I say, it's my first time using `scp`, when I did my research I've seen that the most common use case with this cmd is always with a remote server involved but never between two local machines.

But since computer could be "used as server", I try to stick to the method of the article I'm based on, but maybe methods such as RDP (Remote desktop protocol) or even simply exchange file via USB could be more relevant.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

The message

```
ssh: connect to host .. port 22: Connection timed out
```

suggests that port 22 is not open on the destination computer.

In order to connect via ssh, check that an ssh server service is running on the destination computer. Besides that, make sure that its firewall does not block incoming connections on port 22.