# Port 22 won't open even after enabling it on Windows Firewall settings

Tags: ssh, firewall, port-forwarding, scp, windows-firewall

I'm currently trying to transfer file between my two local computer (laptop running Linux & PC Windows 10) by SHH using `scp` cmd, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1679849/share-file-between-different-local-machine-using-scp-cmd)

I'm trying to transfer from Linux laptop to Windows PC.

But unfortunately, after creating a new inbound rule in Windows firewall settings, my port 22 is still not open.

I've checked that my port isn't open by using this command :

```
netstat -a -n
```

and

```
netstat -ab
```

I've also checked that my rule is enabled :

```
netsh firewall show config
```

and it returns :

```
22     TCP       Activer Entrant               SSH
```

So it's supposed to work, any clue on where the problem might come from ?

Could there be a conflict between user because I'm using WSL2 in order to run Ubuntu ? Like my username in the win shell different from the Ubuntu's one ?

**UPDATE : disable Windows Firewall, do not allow connection on port 22.**

**UPDATE : ssh-server wasn't enabled on Windows machine**

I've checked it by typing `sudo service ssh status`
on Linux shell from my Windows machine

so I follow instruction [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse#start-and-configure-openssh-server)

Then I knew that ssh was already installed and OpenSSH too using this cmd in PowerShell :

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH*'
```

Returns :

```
Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed
```

Then I use these cmd :

```
# Install the OpenSSH Client
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

# Install the OpenSSH Server
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

which both returns :

```
Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False
```

then I've started OpenSSH server :

```
# Start the sshd service
Start-Service sshd

# OPTIONAL but recommended:
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'

# Confirm the Firewall rule is configured. It should be created automatically by setup. Run the following to verify
if (!(Get-NetFirewallRule -Name "OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Name, Enabled)) {
    Write-Output "Firewall Rule 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' does not exist, creating it..."
    New-NetFirewallRule -Name 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22
} else {
    Write-Output "Firewall rule 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' has been created and exists."
}
```

Returns : `Firewall rule 'OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP' has been created and exists.`

But then I've tried to connect to OpenSSH server using this cmd :

```
ssh username@servername
```

but I still won't be able to connect, it returns :

```
ssh: connect to host XX.XXX.X.XXX port 22: Connection timed out
```

I've made sure that I was running PowerShell as an administrator

I made sure my port 22 is now open :

```
netstat -a -n
```

returns :

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

then i've typed :

```
netstat -a -b -n
```

Returns :

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [sshd.exe]
```

and

```
TCP    [::]:22                [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [sshd.exe]
```

Also, `netsh firewall show config` returns :

```
Domaine configuration du profil :
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Mode d’opération = Activer
Mode d’exception                    = Activer
Mode réponse multidiff/transmission = Activer
Mode de notification = Activer

Configuration des programmes autorisés pour le profil Domaine :
Mode     Direction du trafic  Nom / programme
-------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration de port pour le profil Domaine :
Port   Protocole Mode     Direction du trafic   Nom
-------------------------------------------------------------------
22     TCP       Activer Entrant               SSH
53     TCP       Activer Entrant               Realtek AP UDP Prot
1542   UDP       Activer Entrant               Realtek WPS UDP Prot
1542   UDP       Activer Entrant               Realtek WPS TCP Prot

Standard configuration du profil (en cours) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Mode d’opération = Activer
Mode d’exception                    = Activer
Mode réponse multidiff/transmission = Activer
Mode de notification = Activer

Configuration de service pour le profil Standard :
Mode     Personnalisé Nom
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Activer  Non         Recherche du réseau

Configuration des programmes autorisés pour le profil Standard :
Mode     Direction du trafic  Nom / programme
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Activer  Entrant              audiorelay-tcp-private / C:\Program Files (x86)\AudioRelay\AudioRelay.exe

Configuration de port pour le profil Standard :
Port   Protocole Mode     Direction du trafic   Nom
-------------------------------------------------------------------
22     TCP       Activer Entrant               SSH
53     TCP       Activer Entrant               Realtek AP UDP Prot
1542   UDP       Activer Entrant               Realtek WPS UDP Prot
1542   UDP       Activer Entrant               Realtek WPS TCP Prot

Configuration du journal :
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Emplacement du fichier     = C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
Taille maximale de fichier = 4096 Ko
Paquets abandonnés         = Désactiver
Connexions                 = Désactiver
```

File

```
C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
```

is empty.

**UPDATE : after scratching my head a little more, I remembered that I currently use a "public" Ethernet connection provided by my university residency.**

So I look for my default gateway IP by typing `ipconfig` then typed the address in a Chrome tab, but it doesn't worked

*then I remembered I was using uni internet

I go to their router setting page and look for my IP address and found out that it was neither the one I find when typing "what'is my IP" on the internet, nor the one who appears to be the default gateway in the console.

**The IP declared by my uni router match the IPv4 in my network settings**

But when I try to access this IP in a tab, I get : `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Also, after figured out what my real IP was, I try again to connect to SSH with the IPv4 address. I get :

```
The authenticity of host 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx (xx.xxx.xxx.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is .
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Typed `yes`, then :

```
Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Connection reset by xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22
```

**But it didn't ask for any password**

So typed again `ssh username@servername` in order to connect, but I get ask for a password

I tried few ones and get `Permission denied, please try again.` for each except the last one where I get

```
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Comment: Are you trying to SCP from your Ubuntu to Windows or the other way? If you're copying from Ubuntu to Windows, does your Windows system have SSH server enabled? If it does, could you please add full outputs of `netstat -a -b -n` and `netsh firewall show config`? Please don't answer in a comment, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1680286/edit) your question to add new info instead.

Comment: Glad to see you again @Peregrino69

Comment: Glad to be rembembered, I guess :-D Something's listening port 22 now, we can assume it's the SSH server (the -b option would confirm). Only thing left now should be allowing incoming SSH through Win firewall. However [this Bleepingcomputer article](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-bypasses-the-windows-10-firewall/) claims that WSL2 actually bypasses Win firewall entirely. Whichever way, I'd use Windows tools to manage Windows functions and services.

Comment: I've mad edits for `netstat -a -b -n` and `netsh firewall show config`, also as I say previously I've already enable an inbound rule for port 22 in Windows firewall. @Peregrino69

Comment: Yeah, you have, and with my non-existent French it looks correct. Baffles me... check if you can see some hints in `C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log`.

Comment: The Firewall file is empty @Peregrino69

Comment: I've made edits and found out that the IP address wasn't the right one, I've been able somehow to add this IP to the list of known host but couldn't figure what password to use in order to connect, maybe I need to set up my SSH keys @Peregrino69

Comment: Hi @Peregrino69, in order to connect to SSH I've checked that no keys were already in my .ssh file, then I've created new one by using `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` cmd and add a password to it. Then I start SSH-agent : `Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual` , `Start-Service ssh-agent` , `Get-Service ssh-agent`. After that, I've added the keys to the agent : `ssh-add ~\.ssh\id_ed25519` and type a password to it. But I'm still unable to connect to SHH and get `Permission denied, please try again.`. I think I get something wrong, but can't figure out what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research I figured out that due to the fact I was using my university internet connection, my IP address was neither the one obtained by typing "what's my IP" on Google, nor my default gateway IP in the console.

According to the documentation on the service page of my uni router, **it was my IPv4 address**.

From there, I was able to send the right request in order to check if my port was open and to connect to SSH.